# How to connect metamask wallet in Mobile Platform of Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blockchain

I have already made my normal 3D Game and need to be integrated with NFT.
So the first thing I need to do is connecting metamask in Standalone/Mobile Platform.

I tried using web3 but only works in WebGL.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got stuck with this problem for a week.
I imported Web3 unity package in my project and use [DllImport("__internal")] for connecting its function in web3.jslib plugin.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; 
public class MobileLogin : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void MobileConnect();

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern string ConnectAccount();

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void SetConnectAccount(string value);

private int expirationTime;
private string account; 

public void OnLogin()
{
    MobileConnect();
    OnConnected();
}

async private void OnConnected()
{
    account = ConnectAccount();
    while (account == "") {
        await new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        account = ConnectAccount();
    };
    // save account for next scene
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Account", account);
    // reset login message
    SetConnectAccount("");
    // load next scene
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
}

public void OnSkip(){
    // move to next scene
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);    
}}
```

But when it runs, I got with this error:

```
EntryPointNotFoundException: MobileConnect
WebLogin.OnLogin () (at Assets/Web3Unity/Scripts/Scenes/WebLogin.cs:23)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at 
<7d87237cea3743d093e22c5b98f74fba>:0)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at 
<7d87237cea3743d093e22c5b98f74fba>:0)
```

Comment: Hi, @Nikola. Thanx for your answer. I tried web3.jslib importing but the same error happened.